# How to switch to external monitor or clone main one while main one is broken?

Tags: 14.04, monitor

I have my laptop and the screen is broken on it. I have an external monitor and I want to duplicate the screens so I can see what I am doing, but I can't see the main screen so I can switch that.

Dose anyone have any ideas at all? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What model laptop is it?  Some have a dedicated function key for turning on the external monitor and in some cases this works in Ubuntu.

Comment: Another option.  United Airlines broke my daughter's laptop screen. Of course, they wouldn't pay, but I was able to find a replacement for under $70, and found a YouTube video to guide me in installing it. It took under 30 minutes.

Comment: If you connect a second screen, does it work? If so, in what configuration?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu , As there is no command outputs you can provide. Could you [edit] the question and add more details as you could: brand&model of the laptop, graphic card, driver used for graphic card?

Answer (score 0):

As Thomasrutter mentioned, it depends on the model of laptop. Almost all have dedicated key strokes to duplicate the screens. For Dell laptops here is an easy guide: https://askleo.com/how_do_i_connect_a_monitor_to_my_laptop_and_have_it_work/

If you are on a Mac, I believe the shortcut is "Command + F1"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without looking at the screen by going to the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type in:

```
sudo apt-get -y install xrandr *wait for 5-10 seconds*
xrandr --output VGA --auto
```

You can try multiple attempts with different names instead of `VGA` like `VGA1`, `VGA2`, `VGA-0`, `VGA-1`,...

Or if you use HDMI, you can try `HDMI`, `HDMI1`,...